# How do I add up-sells for every product on my WooCommerce Site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have over 70 products on my WooCommerce website and I want to add up-sell products onto every single one. How can I achieve this?

I've tried bulk selecting every product and pressing edit, but up-sell products is not an option. Only things like changing category, etc.

I dont want to have to go through every product and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a spreadsheet of your data then use a plugin to update your products. The meta key for upsells is _upsell_ids and the meta value is an array of ids.
I've used WP All Import before with success. I've listed another I found that I haven't used but looks similar.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

You could do this without a plugin but this way should be straightforward. I highly recommend you make a copy of your postmeta table first or try it out on a test table until it works properly.

Comment: Thank you i think this is the best way to do it, however, are there any plugins that are free that you know of?

Comment: The plugins I linked to are free :)